# SharePoint 2007 Viewing a summary of data from subsites on root site through webparts

Tags: sharepoint-2007, project-management, web-parts

I am looking for a way to display a summary of several lists (from several subsites) on one summary page on my root site by way of project management for several teams. I have tried various methods such as the content query webpart and page viewer webpart but neither achieve what I want to display.

The content query web part only displays the title of my projects, whereas I would like to also see the due date and % complete of each. I have read several blogs about how to edit files in the Style Library to display extra fields; unfortunately this is not an option for me as there are many other sites which rely on this Style Library so I do not have permission to alter it.

The Page Viewer web part looks messy. What I was thinking of doing was to create a page in each subsite containg the information I need and then to have several page viewer web parts in a row on my root site, but it looks awful.

Does anyone know if it is possible to to choose the "file" option in the page viewer web part and specify a .webpart file as the file to view? This would solve my problem.

Any other suggestions to achieve what I want to achieve are more than welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Content Query Web Part (CQWP) would work best for you.

Do you know:

1. You can change the location of your custom XSLT used by CQWP to point to any other location rather than central Style Library. This way you can create CQWP web parts which do not point to main XSLT used by other sites , but your customized XSLT stored in local doc lib.

You can set this property in your .webpart file

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.cmsdataformwebpart.itemxsllink.aspx